# jQuery autocomplete multiple input, each with unique array

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've noticed this question has been asked for multiple input boxes, but what about when each input box must have a unique word array?

I am attempting to use jQuery Autocomplete plugin to attach the function to multiple inputs, each with a unique array of words.  This array is populated from text in a nearby input within a local span.  Each span has an input with different values to populate the array, and an input for autocomplete.
The function is only using the last populated array, instead of the current autocomplete has been assigned to.

This is the outputted html:

```
<?php
            foreach($caseanswers as $key=>$answer){
                    if($answer['input_req']===$term['input_req']){

                            echo '<span class="answer">
                            <textarea class="answertext" id="answer'.$answer['id'].'" disabled>'.$answer['answer'].'</textarea>
                            <div class="ui-widget"><textarea class="autocomplete"></textarea></div>
                            <br/><input type="button" onclick=RUDanswer(this) value="Edit"><input type="button"onclick=RUDanswer(this) value="Delete"></span><br/>';
                    }
            }

?>
```

This is the jQuery code (it's already in a jquery wrapper, left out)

```
<script>
$(".autocomplete").each(function(){
            //alert($(this).val());
            acompletebox=$(this);

            function split(val){
                    return val.split(/\s/);
            }
            function extractLast(term){
                    return split(term).pop();
            }

            availableTags=acompletebox.parents('span.answer').find('.answertext').val().split(" ");
//              acompletebox.parents('span.answer').find('.answertext').val().split(" ");
//              console.log(availableTags);
            // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
            $(this).on("keydown", function(event){
                    if(event.keyCode===$.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active){
                            event.preventDefault();
                    }
            })
            $(this).autocomplete({
//                availableTags=acompletebox.parents('span.answer').find('.answertext').val().split(" ");

                    minLength: 3, source: function(request, response){
                    //delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
                    },
                    focus:function(){
                    //prevent value inserted on focus
                            return false;
                    },
                    select:function(event, ui){
                            var terms=split(this.value);
                            //remove the current input
                            terms.pop();
                            //add the selected item
                            terms.push(ui.item.value);
                            //add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                            terms.push("");
                            this.value=terms.join(" ");
                            return false;
                    }
            });
    });
</script>
```

I guess the question would be, how do I assign the autocomplete datasource with a unique array for each input?
Thanks for all the help you savy hobby coders!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not ideal, the .each() function can be replaced with .focus, or other on select functions.  It must recompile the list everytime a hover happens, which could be expensive computationally if the data comes from an outside source, however it functions with this simple change.